# Code tag not displaying text inside tags

Tags: html

I have been trying for some time to do something very simple and which should work according to many sources. The problem is when I'm using the code tag inside HTML like this:

```
<code> #include <iostream> </code>
```

I desire the output to produce

```
#include <iostream>
```

but the only thing I'm getting is

```
#include
```

So, it seems like I'm having a problem with text inside tags, which doesn't seem very normal...

Now I tried to do the following

```
<code> #include < iostream> </code>
```

which indeed produces and supports my theory.

```
#include < iostream>
```

Trying out the first example with the `<xmp> </xmp>` tag gives me the correct output but this shouldn't be used and doesn't work very well with my syntax highlight. Also, I figured it might have to do something with my browser so I tried out the same example on 3 different browsers, and the results were all the same. I don't see what the problem could be. Has anyone seen anything like this before and know how to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use the character codes like this:

```
<code> #include &lt;iostream&gt; </code>
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I could not find that answer... I don't get why people downvote anyways, the question was not phrased incorrectly or lacked information.